# UnicodeDecodeError: Error al ejecutar un código Python

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

Buenos días,

Estoy teniendo problemas al ejecutar un código en Python bastante básico por temas de codificación. El error que obtengo es:

```
C:\Python27>python C:\bd\ej2.py
utf8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bd\ej2.py", line 11, in <module>
    db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 252, in close
    self.cmd_quit()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 581, in cmd_quit
    self._socket.send(packet, 0, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 143, in send_plain
    errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\errors.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.msg = self.msg % values
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 19: invalid continuation byte
```

En realidad ese error pone utf8 porque he cambiado la codificación vía código a utf8. Si lo dejo quitando todo el tema del uso de la librería sys para el cambio el error me lo da diciendo que el problema es ascii.

El código es este:

```
import mysql.connector
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
config = {
    'user':'user',
    'passwd':'mysql',
    'db':'sakila'
}
db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)  
curso=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select * from actor")
db.close()
```

El problema es en la parte de la conexión. Creo que es un problema con los ** y su codificación. En una versión anterior usé esta línea para conectar:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(user="user",passwd="mysql",db="sakila")
```

Y daba el mismo tipo de error (supongo que por las comillas).

He revisado en notepad++ la codificación, siendo UTF-8. He probado a guardarlo como utf-8 desde noted de Windows y.. ya no tengo muy claro que más puedo hacer.

Apreciaría cualquier ayuda

gracias

Comment: El problema no es con la codificación usada para el código, probablemente este causado por el propio módulo mysql. ¿Podrías colocar la traza completa del error y no solo la última línea?

Comment: Y qué pasa si quitas el `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`? Esa operación no hace nada en python 3 y en python2 puede arrojar errores cuando concatenas implícitamente un string UTF-8 con otra codificación, o con la salida de un `str(variable)` que puede estar ocurriendo implíticamente al abrir conexión.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla he adjuntado la traza. amenadiel probé también sin el setdefault.. (en realidad estaba así por defecto). Estoy en este caso con Python 2.7

Comment: El error es al intentar codificar  la cadena necesaria para mostrar un error del propio conector. El error primario parece ser un error 2055 en el conector que  indica una conexión perdida con el servidor MySQL.  Al intentar lanzar la excepción (codificar el mensaje a mostrar en esta) se produce el problema de encoding.  Mírate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729962/the-python-and-install-mysqlconnector, a ver si consigues al menos obtener el error primario, no uso este módulo (suelo usar  MySQLdb), por norma general nunca debería usarse `setdefaultencoding`.

Comment: Hola, efectivamente el problema finalmente estaba en que la BD no estaba levantada. No caí en ese problema al ver un error de codificación. Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda